# iOS clang error no file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, pch

I''m very unfamiliar with the iOS build process. I was giving a legacy application that hasn't been touched in a few years, it was targeting iOS 5 before I opened it.
I'm running into an error `Command 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`

I could be wrong but I've browsed a few post and it seems like older xCode cersions didn't have a pch file. Any suggestion on how to get this project running again?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: `cmd + K` or `cmd + shift + K`

Comment: that was the first thing I tried. But when I build the project the error just came back

Answer (score 0):

If this file you are used to bridge OC and Swift，now you should creat a new .header file and Move All Header file Name inside file

and Add Your File Location inside Build setting -> objectiveC Bridging Header

Hope It Works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the .pch file is missing from the project but reference still exists in the Xcode Settings. So, Xcode is searching for the .pch file but couldn't find the same.

I recommend you to update the GPU-Image Framework as this might be the old framework. Otherwise, Try the below steps:

1. Go the Build Settings.
2. Scroll down to the section 'Apple LLVM 8.1- Language'.
3. You'll see the option for 'Prefix Header' with the path to the .pch file.
4. Remove the path from the 'Prefix Header'.

Hope this'll solve your issue.

[image: Screenshot Attached]